# Integrating Google Maps into WinJS

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, winjs

I am very new to HTML, JS, and CSS so I began with a basic tutorial on JS and dove straight into WinJS. Then I followed this tutorial for GoogleMaps: http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/

Then I attempted to merge it into my project and this is where I became stuck. In my itemDetail.html, I have an `<iframe>` and when the project is run its area turns white, then black and nothing shows up.

```
<!--- itemDetail.html --->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>itemDetailPage</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Maps API reference -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/data.js"></script>
    <script src="/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
    <div class="itemdetailpage fragment">
        <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
            <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
            <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                <span class="pagetitle"></span>
            </h1>
        </header>
        <div class="content" aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <article>
                <div>
                    <header>
                        <h2 class="item-title"></h2>
                        <h4 class="item-subtitle"></h4>
                    </header>
                    <iframe id="Map" src="ms-appx-web:///map/map.html" height="400" width="600"></iframe>
                    <div class="item-content"></div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This `<iframe>` connects to map.html.

```
<!--- map.html --->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Google Maps API reference -->
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization">
    </script>

    <!-- mapframe references -->
    <link href="/map/map.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/map/map.js"></script>

    <!-- USGS URL data source 
    <script src="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week"></script>
    -->
</head>

<body>
        <div id="mapdisplay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and that uses map.js

```
//map.js
var map;
var dataResults;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdisplay'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -187.3),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    addMarkers();
}

function addMarkers() {
    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -187.3);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLong,
        map: map
        //icon: getCircle(earthquake.properties.mag)
    });
}

function getCircle(magnitude) {
    return {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: .2,
        scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / Math.PI,
        strokeColor: 'white',
        strokeWeight: .5
    };
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I removed the data gathering from the tutorial and just hard-coded the lat and long in for now. Once I figure this out I have to take the data from itemDetail.js and somehow get it to map.js since my JSON has lat and long data in it.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if that would work but make sure you use an [x-ms-webview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx) instead on an `iframe`.